# jquery to select a dropdown list control in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I am using ASP.net and have a dropdown control.

```
 <asp:DropdownList runat="server" ID = "fieldReadOnlyContent" Enabled="false" class = "attribute"><asp:ListItem value = "0">False</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem value = "1">True</asp:ListItem></asp:DropdownList>
```

I wanted to adjust the dropdown control via the clientside controls qith jquery.  I get the value which it needs to be set to.

```
//d[3] will be either true or false.
$("#fieldReadOnlyContent").val(d[3]);
```

the above attempt didnt seem to set the item to properly enabled.  HOw would i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item is not getting set because `$("#fieldReadOnlyContent").val(d[3]);` will check for the `value`.

For your case

```
if(d[3]=='false'){
 $("#fieldReadOnlyContent").val('0');
}
else
{
 $("#fieldReadOnlyContent").val('1');
}
```

Comment: im going to test this out quick.

Comment: this is the correct answer from what it looks.  Thank you very much Clyde

Comment: @Fallenreaper : No issues. I had got into the same problem a week ago. Hence I knew what was the issue

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#<%=fieldReadOnlyContent.ClientID%>").val(d[3]);
```

Comment: this will work but you will no longer be able to dynamically add/modify controls onthe page, if that where required...

Answer (score 0):

`fieldReadOnlyContent` is not necessarily the ID given to the client-side HTML element.

You can use `ClientIDMode="Static"` server-side to control the client-side ID in .net4.0 ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)), or `<%= fieldReadOnlyContent.ClientID %>` to inject the client id directly into the javascript otherwise.